# How to properly set the dimensions of an SVG circle?

Tags: html, svg

I am having problems implementing a small circle in html. I just found out about the svg and i think it will allow me to complete my project. I am able to draw a square of 2 pixels by 2 pixels with a black outline of 1 pixel with no problem.

The problem with the circle is with the dimensions of the outline; if I use the value of 1 it is too small, that's why i use a value of 2 and it look good. For some reason the radius is all wrong also, I end up using a radius of 1.5 with the image dimension of 5 by 5 pixels.

Here is the zoomed picture: if you look the first row (first table) the dimensions are different from the second row (second table) this is due to the dimensions of 5 by 5 pixels of the circle?

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code; how do i fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg height="5" width="5">
            <circle cx="2.5" cy="2.5" r="1.5" stroke="black" fill="yellow">
            </circle>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- The second table starts here -->
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is simply because one SVG has `width="5"` and all others have `width="4"`.

Comment: you are correct; so what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` and `height` attributes of an element, if supported, usually set its dimensions in pixels.
So your problem essentially boils down to 5 not being equal to 4.

The (in my opinion) cleanest way of solving this would be to change that one SVG's dimensions to 4x4 and multiply the values used in the circle attributes by 4/5:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg height="4" width="4">
            <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.2" stroke="black" fill="yellow">
            </circle>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- The second table starts here -->
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Another way would be to make use of the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute.
You'd set the `width` and `height` attributes of the SVG in question to `4`, but the `viewBox` to `0 0 5 5`.
This way, the outer dimensions will become 4 by 4 pixels, but elements inside the SVG will be scaled and positioned as if the top left corner was (0,0) and the bottom right corner way (5,5).
This has the advantage of being easily scalable without disrupting any proportions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg height="4" width="4" viewBox="0 0 5 5">
            <circle cx="2.5" cy="2.5" r="1.5" stroke="black" fill="yellow">
            </circle>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- The second table starts here -->
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
    <td valign="middle">
        <svg width="4" height="4">
            <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:2;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you zoom the tables you will see the circle cut at the 3 and 6 o'clock .

Comment: Perfect, i just changed the radius to "r=1.5" and it worked!